# Read property file placed inside in package under src/test/resource in maven

Tags: java, maven, properties, nullpointerexception, file-handling

My maven structure looks as below:

Have placed property file inside package under src/test/resources
And I trying to read from java class( Browser Test) under src/test/java

I am using below code to ready file, but the getting NullPointerException.

```
public Static Properties CONFIG 
CONFIG = new Properties();
InputStream inputStream = BrowserTest.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
CONFIG.load(inputStream);


[31mMessage: [0m[31mjava.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put the resource files in the root of the `src/test/resources` tree (`src/test/resources/application.properties`). Then use a `static` initialization block. Like,

```
public static Properties CONFIG = new Properties();
static {
    try {
        CONFIG.load(BrowserTest.class.getResourceAsStream(
                "application.properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You getting NullPointerException because both `BrowserTest.java` and `application.properties` are in different packages.

Either

1. Move `application.properties` from `com.philips.rs.properties` to `com.philips.rs.utils` and read it directly.

   ```
   String filename = "application.properties";
   InputStream inputStream = BrowserTest.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
   CONFIG.load(inputStream);
   ```
2. Or change the `filename` to `"/com/philips/rs/properties/application.properties"`

   ```
   String filename = "/com/philips/rs/properties/application.properties";
   InputStream inputStream = BrowserTest.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
   CONFIG.load(inputStream);
   ```

Better explaination can find from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-